# Finding solution of a set of equations such that the results are perfect squares.

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, square-numbers

Constraints: $f^2<g^2<a^2$
The equations are 
$2g^2−f^2=A$
$2a^2−f^2=B$
$g^2−f^2+a^2=C$
$g^2−2f^2+2a^2=D$
$2g^2−3f^2+2a^2=E$
$2g^2−2f^2+a^2=F$

Find the values of $a$, $f$ and $g$ such that the results of all above equations (capital lettered variables) are a perfect square.

How do I go about solving this? How many solutions are possible? What could be one trivial solution?

Please provide some useful insight or point to a learning resource before downvoting. Any edits are welcome as well.

Comment: `What could be one trivial solution?` $\;f=g=a$ with an arbitrary $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, for example, do something like

$$(I)\ \  g^2-f^2+a^2=C $$
$$(II)\ \ g^2-2f^2+2a^2= D $$
so
$$-(I)+(II) = -f+a^2 = D-C$$

and use this fact to solve the other expressions, such as
$$2a^2-f^2 = B = a^2 +a^2-f^2 =a^2+ D-C$$
and so
$$a^2=B+C-D$$